# How to hide the the navigationbar that present in pdf viewer plugin flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, mobile

I need to hide the navigation bar that present  default in the pdfviewer plugin flutter.I used to change the value of showNavigation value to false but it doesn't work .I use the plugin **flutter_plugin_pdf_viewer:any**  here is my code:

```
       Containe(  width:130,
               
                   height:130,
               
                 margin:EdgeInsets.all(20.0),
                 child:PDFViewer(document:doc2,
                showNavigation : false,/*here is my issue ,when i set like this it shows nothing in the UI*/ ),)
```

Answer (score 0):

This plugin solves this issue please check the below link

https://github.com/lohanidamodar/pdf_viewer/pull/2

Use this plugin

```
advance_pdf_viewer: any
```

Answer (score 0):

I have solved this issue by changing source code of this plugin. for hiding navigation tool bar in the pdf viewer plugin use  this plugin for viewing only single page from pdf :)

https://github.com/SmilingDeveloper/newpdf_viewer.git